# How to not present View Controller Modally

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

[image][image: ph]I am trying to present a home screen when user logs in (or has previously logged in). The home screen is being displayed, but modally. How do I display it normally?

Example:

```
        if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "appleAuthorizedUserIdKey") != nil {
                // move to main view
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "LogIn", sender: nil)
```

And the segue kind is set to 'show' in storyboard. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You controller from where you are performing segue needs to be embed in `UINavigationController` to show it Normally otherwise it will show it modally

Comment: Ok, that one is embedded in NavigationController and so is the one it is segueing to. (The segue points to the other embedded NavigationController).

Comment: added photo of storyboard.

Comment: okay .. great .. so far everything is good .. can you show the segue detail .. where you set it `show`

Comment: just added that one

Comment: you dont need navigationController in between ... add segue directly to controller will solve your problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219216/discussion-between-trevpennington-and-jawadali).